# How to Loop/Parse SOAP response in PHP to get all the results

Tags: php, soap, soapui

I  am new to PHP and SOAP and trying to get values SOAP response in my PHP code.
With below code I am able to get one set of the response but not all three.

```
if (count($triphistory->TripHistoryList) > 0) {
           $trip_history_data = $triphistory->TripHistoryList[0];
```

Below is SOAP response and I have to get all the values of 'TripHistoryList'.

```
<ns2:TripHistoryList>
        <ns2:TagSerialNumber>6501099999999</ns2:TagSerialNumber>
        <ns2:PlateNumber>ABCD</ns2:PlateNumber>
        <ns2:PlateState>VA</ns2:PlateState>
        <ns2:TxnTime>2018-07-20T23:22:30.080-04:00</ns2:TxnTime>
        <ns2:PlazaId>495010</ns2:PlazaId>
        <ns2:Zone>1</ns2:Zone>
        <ns2:HovSW>H</ns2:HovSW>
        <ns2:HovNom>H</ns2:HovNom>
     </ns2:TripHistoryList>
     <ns2:TripHistoryList>
        <ns2:TagSerialNumber>6501099999999</ns2:TagSerialNumber>
        <ns2:PlateNumber>XYZA</ns2:PlateNumber>
        <ns2:PlateState>VA</ns2:PlateState>
        <ns2:TxnTime>2018-07-20T23:22:30.080-04:00</ns2:TxnTime>
        <ns2:PlazaId>951010</ns2:PlazaId>
        <ns2:Zone>1</ns2:Zone>
        <ns2:HovSW>H</ns2:HovSW>
        <ns2:HovNom>H</ns2:HovNom>
     </ns2:TripHistoryList>
     <ns2:TripHistoryList>
        <ns2:TagSerialNumber>6501099999999</ns2:TagSerialNumber>
        <ns2:PlateNumber>UGHF</ns2:PlateNumber>
        <ns2:PlateState>VA</ns2:PlateState>
        <ns2:TxnTime>2018-07-20T23:22:30.080-04:00</ns2:TxnTime>
        <ns2:PlazaId>951010</ns2:PlazaId>
        <ns2:Zone>1</ns2:Zone>
        <ns2:HovSW>T</ns2:HovSW>
        <ns2:HovNom>T</ns2:HovNom>
     </ns2:TripHistoryList>
```

Just for Info: I am displaying the output as below. Any Help is appreciated

```
<tbody>
        <tr>
            <th width="20%">Tag Serial Number</th>
            <th width="20%">Plate_Number</th>
            <th width="20%">REAR PLATE JURISDICTION</th>
            <th width="20%">TXN TIMESTAMP</th>
            <th width="20%">PLAZA ID</th>
            <th width="20%">ZONE LANE</th>
            <th width="20%">LINK ID</th>
            <th width="20%">HOV SW</th>
            <th width="20%">HOV NOM Due</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
               <td width="20%"><?php e($trip_history_data->TagSerialNumber); ?></td>
              <td width="20%"><?php e($trip_history_data->PlateNumber); ?></td>
              <td width="20%"><?php e($trip_history_data->PlateState); ?></td>
               <td width="20%"><?php e($trip_history_data->TxnTime); ?></td>
              <td width="20%"><?php e($trip_history_data->PlazaId); ?></td>
              <td width="20%"><?php e($trip_history_data->Zone); ?></td>
             <td width="20%"><?php e($trip_history_data->PlazaId); ?></td>
             <td width="20%"><?php e($trip_history_data->HovSW); ?></td>
              <td width="20%"><?php e($trip_history_data->HovNom); ?></td>
 </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code to

```
<?php 
          foreach($trip_history_data as $data) {
?>
<tr>
               <td width="20%"><?php e($data->TagSerialNumber); ?></td>
              <td width="20%"><?php e($data->PlateNumber); ?></td>
              <td width="20%"><?php e($data->PlateState); ?></td>
               <td width="20%"><?php e($data->TxnTime); ?></td>
              <td width="20%"><?php e($data->PlazaId); ?></td>
              <td width="20%"><?php e($data->Zone); ?></td>
             <td width="20%"><?php e($data->PlazaId); ?></td>
             <td width="20%"><?php e($data->HovSW); ?></td>
              <td width="20%"><?php e($data->HovNom); ?></td>
 </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Do I need to change this to?  

$trip_history_data = $triphistory->TripHistoryList[0];
As 0 index is giving first result so do I need to remove the index there?

Comment: Great. Can you please choose my answer as the answer. :)